# How can I create a custom TLD (for an Intranet) on my Wi-Fi network with a Windows computer and Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, router, intranet, tld

Can you please explain to me how I would do this, starting with the installation of Apache?

Are there multiple ways to do this? I would like the domain (eg `http://intranet`) available when you connect to the network, without editing the `hosts` file on every computer. Is that possible?

I would also like to create subdomains for my local URLs (eg `http://site.intranet`); can you tell me how to do this in Apache, and how to configure it?

Would I have to rename my computer to `intranet`, or is there another way to map the domain without editing each computer's configuration or workgroup (possibly through my router's settings)?

I would be very grateful if you could help me understand my options better, and tell me how to set up the server; thank you!

Comment: Really don't do this. "Custom" TLDs break enough RFCs that you should just buy the domain name that you want to use internally and use it. A few bucks a year isn't an overwhelming price.

Comment: @MDMarra I have several domain names, but I want to do this as a hobby project, really.

Comment: I mostly agree with @MDMarra so consider buying the `example.com` domain and serving a separate `corp.example.com` domain from DNS servers reachable only from "internal" addresses.

Comment: @LuisBruno I could do that, but, as I said, I am mostly doing this as a hobby project.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to preach to the choir. It's just too easy to go with the default `example.local` domain that I just wanted to get that out in the clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all hinges on DNS. You have to make sure that the DNS name `intranet` gets resolved to an IP address. I know how to do this only one way: installing my own DHCP and DNS service for the infrastructure. Bonjour-style should work as well, but I have no experience doing it that way.

The operating systems I know of support DNS suffixes, like `.local` or `example.corp`. You'll control the DHCP server on your network, correct? Lets assume it will give out addresses like `192.168.13.128`, with a `255.255.255.0` network mask and most importantly, it will give out the address of a DNS server that knows how to answer authoritatively over the `example.corp` zone and it will say to the DHCP clients that their DNS domain is `example.corp`. Most operating systems will then try to access `http://intranet.example.corp` if you type `http://intranet`.

This is how the short-names will work. Onwards to name-based virtual-hosting, like @Iain said. Let's assume your Apache's configuration says:

```
Listen *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I'll assume the Apache server has the `192.168.13.1/24` IP address. I'd put an `A` record like `s01.srv.example.corp.` pointing at `192.168.13.1` and a `CNAME` like `intranet.example.corp.` pointing at `s01.srv.example.corp.` and if you need sub-sites I'd put in `site.intranet.example.corp.` as well, pointing at the full `s01.srv` DNS name.

Back to the Apache configuration: you'll need to add virtual-hosts like these:

```
# this matches the NameVirtualHost directive and
# loosely matches the Listen directive; it could also be:
# NameVirtualHost 192.168.13.1:80 and you'd change this below as well
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # notice you'll need both of these;
    # they must match what's in the browser Location bar
    ServerName intranet.example.corp
    ServerAlias intranet

    # sorry for the Unix-style paths, I avoid Windows a bit
    DocumentRoot /var/www/intranet.example.corp
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't mind expanding on this, if you need help. Please feel free to ask!

Answer (score 2):

The technology you are after is [name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). You would typically configure your DNS server with an [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) or [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record that for each domain/subdomain that you want to serve that points to the address of your apache server.

You then use name-based virtual hosting to configure a vhost for each domain/subdomain.

Comment: Would I need to set up the DNS on my router? How would I do that?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at http://www.opennicproject.org they specialize in custom TLDs. They have a lot of information about setting them up and all their domains are free to use. My favorite is .geek lol then .pirate :P

You could also apply for a TLD now if you're a millionaire. Since I'm not it's open nic for me.

Comment: OpenNIC, like it's predecessor [AlterNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlterNIC) ***Breaks The Internet***. As [a site for professionals](http://serverfault.com/faq) recommendations for things that [Break The Internet](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2826) are not really appropriate here.